# glTexImage2D 'target is not valid'

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d, textures

I am writing a game engine, but I'm having a puzzling issue when loading textures.

My code is as follows:

```
//Load to GL
glGenTextures(1, &glTextureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glTextureID);
glTexImage2D(glTextureID, 0, format, width, height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

Stepping through with GL debug output enabled shows that the `glTexImage2D` line gives the error:

> Error has been generated. GL error GL_INVALID_ENUM in (null): (ID: 1938861751)  1 is not valid.

Where format is dependent on the image being loaded, and is determined using `FreeImage`. (Breaks with both `GL_RGBA` and `GL_RED` for respective image types). `width`/`height` is also determined with `FreeImage`, both values being 512 in the `GL_RGBA` case. It is my understanding that these values are valid for both format parameters.

The full code using `FreeImage` is a bit lengthy to include here, and uses multiple threads (I am sure that this code is run on the main thread, and I assert so prior to these lines).

The following also does not work:

```
glTexImage2D(glTextureID, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

I have not been able to find any other people who have had this error. I have researched how `GL_INVALID_ENUM` can be thrown, but none of the documented ways seem applicable, certainly not with the message I received.

The value of `glTextureID` is not modified between these lines, remaining at '1'.

The same error is also thrown when trying to load additional textures, with the 'target' being different.

My GL context is correctly initialized, since I am able to use other GL functions, and successfully draw untextured polygons.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The fist parameter of [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) is the `target`, which must be `GL_TEXTURE_2D`, `GL_PROXY_TEXTURE_2D`, `GL_TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY` ...

Change your code to:

<s>`glTexImage2D(glTextureID, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);`</s>

```cpp
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, width, height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

Note `glTexImage2D` specifies the two-dimensional texture for the  texture object that is bound to the current [Texture unit](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture#Texture_image_units).

See [OpenGL 4.6 core profile specification - 8.5. TEXTURE IMAGE SPECIFICATION, page 212](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf):

> The command
>
> ```
> void TexImage2D( enum target, int level, int internalformat, sizei width,
>     sizei height, int border, enum format, enum type, const void *data );
> ```
>
> is used to specify a two-dimensional texture image. target must be one of `TEXTURE_2D` for a two-dimensional texture, `TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY` for a onedimensional array texture, `TEXTURE_RECTANGLE` for a rectangle texture, or one of the cube map face targets from table [...]